# Bootstrap selectpicker search box font size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Is it possible to change font size of the search box in Bootstrap select?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_select&stacked=h .  check this link if it is helpful to you

Comment: .selectpicker{ font-size: 12px ! important; } this will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) generates some HTML for you, so the thing you want is to inspect the HTML and then write some CSS to override the attributes given by the library.

CSS:

```
.bs-searchbox > input {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

This should work for you. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```css
.selectpicker{
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), then you can use the following css:

```
.filter-option {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```