# Dynamically created select with SelectPicker class always posts the first opion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have been around stackoverflow trying to find a fix for my selectpicker problem with no similar situation documented. My scenario is totally different so i had to ask the question.

I have a form with a button to dynamically add a new row to the form and assign an id to each of the newly created select inputs.

The javascript to achieve this is

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    if (rowCount < 10) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        var rolCount = table.rows.length;

        for (var j = 0; j < rolCount; j++) {
            row.setAttribute("id", j);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //newline = table.rows[0].cells[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
            //alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type);
            switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    newcell.childNodes[0].id = "select" + rowCount;

                    break;
            }
            //row.setAttribute("id", i);
        }
        $(select).selectpicker('refresh');

    } else {
        alert("Maximum Drug per patient is 10");
    }
}
```

[View Result Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t5tj.png)This code works well and it creates a new row with new input elements. Here is the code of the rows being duplicated/cloned.

```
<TD>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
</TD>
<TD>
    <select name="drugs[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control drugs" data-live-search="true">
                <?php echo $drug_options; ?>
    </select>
</TD>
<TD>
    <select name="qty[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control">
        <option>Qty</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</TD>
<td>
    <select name="dosage[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control" data-live-search="true">
            <?php echo $dosage_options; ?>
     </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="duration[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control" data-live-search="true">
              <?php echo $duration_options; ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

However when i submit the form all the select menus with class="selectpicker with-search form-control" all post the value of the first option regardless of the selection made. [Here is the Debug View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1MLL.png) and here is the result in the database

Like i stated earlier i have seen similar issues on stackoverflow but none of them where helpful to me, even the answered ones.

I hope there would be someone out there that can spot the bug or recommend a fix. Thanks in advance

just for the record this is the output of the html on inspection just for the selectpicker

`

```
 <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select with-search form-control drugs">            

 <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-  toggle="dropdown" title="Aciclovir 100mg (11 )">
 <span class="filter-option pull-left">Aciclovir 100mg (11 )</span>
 &nbsp;
 <span class="bs-caret">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </span>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu open">
 <div class="bs-searchbox">
 <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text">
 </div>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">

 <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
 <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
 <span class="text">Aciclovir 100mg (11 )</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
 </li>

 <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Paracetamol 100mg (Emzor) (12 )</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
 <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Paracetamol 250mg (Emzor) (13 )</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>

 <li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Paracetamol 500mg (Emzor) (14 )</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>

 <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Paracetamol 500mg (Pfizer) (15 )</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>

 </ul>
 </div>

 <select name="drugs[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control drugs" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
                <option value="Aciclovir 100mg">Aciclovir 100mg (11 )</option>
 <option value="Paracetamol 100mg (Emzor)">Paracetamol 100mg (Emzor) (12 )</option>
 <option value="Paracetamol 250mg (Emzor)">Paracetamol 250mg (Emzor) (13 )</option>
 <option value="Paracetamol 500mg (Emzor)">Paracetamol 500mg (Emzor) (14 )</option>
 <option value="Paracetamol 500mg (Pfizer)">Paracetamol 500mg (Pfizer) (15 )</option>
                </select></div>`
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of the question.

Comment: What does "however when i sub,it the form all the selects with" mean?

Comment: Pardon me for the typos. I meant to say

Comment: "However when i submit the form, all the selct menus with class="selectpicker with-search form-control" .......

Comment: Please edit your answer to correct the typos instead

Comment: Are you assigning unique `id`'s to the newly created rows? It sounds like they're not unique.

Comment: Using Firebug (The Browser Inspection Tool) I can see that the selectpicker class has some hidden html attached to it. for example i.e

Comment: an html like so <select name="drugs[]" class="selectpicker with-search form-control drugs" data-live-search="true">
                 <?php echo $drug_options; ?>
                 </select> appears like this in the firebug inspection panel                     <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select with-search form-control drugs">

<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Aciclovir 100mg (11 )">
<span class="filter-option pull-left">Aciclovir 100mg (11 )</span>
<span class="bs-caret">
<span class="caret"></span>
</span>
</button>

Comment: So i'm suspecting that it is the button title that is being submitted and not the selection. What do you think

Answer (score 0):

### From what you have posted its hard to get the full picture, however i believe this may be a solution

If you are using JavaScript to create these extra fields then using PHP to fill the options will not work as PHP is server side script and loads before.

Once the page has loaded, PHP has done its job and cannot be called again, therefore by creating new elements the php wont have any effect, giving you "the same results"

My solution for this would be to use [HttpXML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) (javascript also called ajax) to dynamically load all the new data that would be required. As this will ask a page that hasnt loaded to parse the data back, you will get an update version.

Alternatively, you can use your selection from the drug type, post this to another page as a [multi-phase form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZVO8IWkFtg) (or same page with a php value of

```
if(isset($_POST['drug']) && $_POST['drugs'] == 'paracetemol')){
$options = ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Christopher Craven, but i don't seem to have any issues with the extra fields generated. I am able to populate options in the select fields. The problem is, it is posting the first option for each of the select menus. You might be right about it not setting unique id's.

Comment: It could have something to do with you field names being abcd[] instead of just abcd. I am unsure as to why you would require [] in the names

Comment: All the new fields enter all their data in one table field. That means if i have 3 new rows, the drugs field will accept the three selections for dugs. The Qty field will accept the three selections on quantity etc. hence the name[]

Comment: Can you post the php you are using for dosage_options ect

Comment: $drug_options ='';
while ($drug_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($drugs))
{ $selected = ($drug_row['benefititem'] == $_POST['drugs']) ?  ' selected="selected"': '';
    $drug_options .= "<option value=\"{$drug_row['benefititem']}\"{$selected}>".ucfirst($drug_row['benefititem'])." (".ucfirst($drug_row['benefitamount'])." )</option>\n";
}

Comment: Why have you encased drug row in {} under value. Also what is your pourpose of $selected in the options. Simplise your code to find the error. First move ucfirst to a separate variable above then put that in e.g. $captial_drug this will help you see a potential problem.

Comment: {} represents <? ?> when echoing php in html. The purpose of selected is because my form is both an insert form and an update form.

Comment: Have you right clicked and inspected the element to see what has been outptted?

Comment: Yes i have and i have included the output in my question. I think that is where the issue is the selectpicker is made up of multiple form inputs. I wanna try to overwrite the css as suggested in an answer by @Dragomir Kolev to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152433/bootstrap-selectpicker-search-box-font-size

Comment: The last thing i can suggest is that when ouputting the data try differnt values of the drugs array. I.e 1 2 3 4 for example. Other wise im stumped. Sorry

Comment: i tried using manual values for the dropdown and it is still doing the same thing (Posting the title or the first option if no title is given). How can i share this question with members of the community.

Comment: This already is a shared question. I definitely think its something to do with how youre handling the [ ] part of the form

Comment: Hey @Chris C. I tried it with and without the [] but it still posts the first option. How do i share a screenshot with the group for a visual of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Edith the original post and click the camera

Comment: When you say getting the same result how are you taking the results do you mean database or do you mean output HTML

Comment: When Posting it submits the first option of the select field. When i check the table it shows all the first options of all the select fields. I tried to override the css but that didnt work either. The page did not recognize the html generated by the bootstrap.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way you are parsing the data from php to your database. How are you doing this? $_POST[drugs][0]

Comment: $drug_list = implode("," $_POST[drugs]); i also tried $drug_list = $_POST[drugs];

Comment: And what is the output of this when you echo it for testing

Comment: Acciclovir 10mg, Acciclovir 10mg, Acciclovir10mg. This is the result i get when i add three select fields to the grid. Gimme a sec to post screenshots of what it is

Comment: Have you tried appending a number to each input field for example name drug[0] drug[1]

Comment: I tried to do that with javascript to append an id attribute to the select field. Works well on http://jsfiddle.net/tcCAG/1/ but not on my own machine. Please note this fiddle is not mine i just paste my html in it and get the desired effect.

Comment: Have you got an online version i can try?

Comment: No i dont. I just editd my question and added 2 pictures (the dynamic fields and the xray of the submit action)

Comment: If you dont use the javascript to add extra columns. Just hard code them, does it work?

Comment: My reason for asking is the first one is probably a hard coded selection and the rest input through javascript

Comment: If i hard code them they work cuz i can manually add unique id's to the select input i.e name="drugs[0]" .... name="drugs[1]"..... etc.